Use a WMS in annotation_spatial of {ggspatial}
I want to use a WMS to add as a basemap in {ggspatial}. However, I can't find the way. I can read the WMS using {terra} but not using {stars}, but then, this raise an error when passed to annotation_spatial.
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(stars)
library(ggplot2)

points <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5, 
  x = (436:440)*1e3,
  y = (4670:4674)*1e3 
) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 25831)

box <- st_bbox(points)

wms <- paste0("https://geoserveis.icgc.cat/servei/catalunya/orto-territorial/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&CRS=EPSG:25831&BBOX=",box[1],",",box[2],",",box[3],",",box[4],"&WIDTH=520&HEIGHT=520&LAYERS=ortofoto_color_vigent&STYLES=&FORMAT=JPEG&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&EXCEPTION=INIMAGE")

orto <- rast(wms)

plotRGB(orto) # This plots the ortophoto correctly

ggplot() +
  annotation_spatial(orto) +
  layer_spatial(points)

#> Error in `layer_spatial.SpatRaster()`:
#> ! Problem while converting geom to grob.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! vector::reserve


You could use terra::geom_spatraster_rgb() instead. You could also use geom_sf() for the sf object. The default behaviour for tidyterra is to simplify/resample the output to speed up plotting. You can adjust the resolution using maxcell =. You can set maxcell = Inf to return all cells but I did not test that on your example SpatRaster as it as 1.152922e+18 cells!
library(ggspatial)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = orto, maxcell = 1e6) +
  layer_spatial(points) +
  theme_minimal()

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = orto, maxcell = 1e6) +
  geom_sf(data = points) +
  theme_minimal()



I was interested in using annotation_spatial because it doesn't train the scales, which is ideal for a basemap. Also to avoid a new dependency to tidyterra. I suppose this is what it is. Thank you!

@JosepPueyo - from what I can tell, annotation_spatial() relies on coord_sf(), which does not like untrained scales. Everything I read regarding coord_sf() appears to confirm it's not possible. Someone more knowledgeable may hopefully know a way to override this behaviour.

This is from the {ggspatial} documentation: "Unlike layer_spatial(), annotation_spatial() layers never train the scales, so they can be used as a backdrop for other layers." https://paleolimbot.github.io/ggspatial/articles/ggspatial.html

@JosepPueyo - yeah, saw that. It makes no mention of terra or SpatRaster so I tried using a RasterBrick and the issue persisted. And none of the code using the built-in example data @ ggpatial GitHub works either (same error). This, together with the fact that no issues have been responded to since 15 December 2022, I've assumed rolling back to older versions might be the only option now.
